# Error in ipynb file for neural net

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

Im kind of a noob, so bear with me here. I have been watching Siraj Raval on youtube, and tried to use the neural net he created in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAICT4Al5Ow. I have two sepparate folders of images, one of cells containg malaria and the other of healthy cells. I as not sure what to use for validation data. I get an error after I use the `load_data`function on the path for where the images are contained, and I'm not sure how to fix this. It seems like one of the packages im using that is supposed to have that function is not working properly.

I have coppied the code from each cell (Im using jupyter notebook) into this text file. The long spaces in between the text are to show they are in different cells. I dont know if this matters or not.

http://textuploader.com/d0nv0

Comment: I removed my answer again. You are missing "from parser import load_data" but that seems to be a custom module not provided by Siraj. I have a project where I load images. I'll be back

Answer (score 0):

Check again [minute 2:45](https://youtu.be/cAICT4Al5Ow?t=2m45s)
You are missing

```
from parser import load_data
```

But this seems to be a custom module that is not provided. What you want is to read all files from a folder into an array/list. Here is a code that can do that to get you started:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import cv2
images = []
images2 = []

folder="somepics"
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if not filename.startswith('.'):
        print(filename)

        #read with PIL
        img = Image.open("{0}/{1}".format(folder, filename))
        print(type(img))
        images.append(img)

        #read with cv2
        img2 = cv2.imread(filename)
        print(type(img2))
        images2.append(img)
```

Remember that images need to be of same size. You might need to reshape them.

Answer (score 0):

You need a *generator*. See [`fit_generator` function section documentation of Keras](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#sequential-model-methods), or better yet use an `ImageDataGenerator`. The next snip of code is copied & pasted from [Building an image classification model using very little data](https://github.com/llSourcell/how_to_make_an_image_classifier/blob/master/demo.ipynb):

**Directory structure**

```
data/
    train/
        dogs/ ### 1024 pictures
            dog001.jpg
            dog002.jpg
            ...
        cats/ ### 1024 pictures
            cat001.jpg
            cat002.jpg
            ...
    validation/
        dogs/ ### 416 pictures
            dog001.jpg
            dog002.jpg
            ...
        cats/ ### 416 pictures
            cat001.jpg
            cat002.jpg
```

**Code**

```
# used to rescale the pixel values from [0, 255] to [0, 1] interval
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# automagically retrieve images and their classes for train and validation sets
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=16,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
```

See the original code in [Building an image classification model using very little data](https://github.com/llSourcell/how_to_make_an_image_classifier/blob/master/demo.ipynb).